# Using Double Quotes as Record Separator in AWK

Tags: parsing, awk

Question says it all. I've tried using `awk 'BEGIN{RS=\"} /Match/{print $0}' input` and every combination of escaping and quoting I could think of. Any Ideas how to pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use \042.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\042"}{}' file
```

or

```
awk -vRS='"' '{}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\""} /Match/{print $0}'
```